# Should possible/partial answers be edited out of a question?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

[This question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37606/is-it-possible-to-disable-a-vehicle-with-microwave-oven-magnetron-from-that-dist) quotes a critique in the question text.

It is my understanding<sup>*</sup> that this should be edited out.
Is that correct? I can't find this on meta yet.

<sup>* First comment under [my question here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32779/one-year-without-beef-saves-3432-trees)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'd say not to delete them outright in all cases, but certainly do so when they are an actual problem to the question, for example when the attempted or partial answer...

- ...makes the question a soapbox post: "I heard that WiFi causes cancer. I've researched the interwebs and I think it does. Can you disprove me?"
- ...limits the type of evidence in the answer in any way: "Livestrong claims that turmeric cures cancer. I've read the papers on google scholar, but I don't trust them. Is there any better evidence?"

On the other hand, I would allow them when they are...

- ...reasons for belief or disbelief: "I heard that WiFi causes cancer. If I put my face next to the router it gets warm, so maybe there's some truth to it. Is it true?"
- ...explanations of what the OP has attempted, but do not limit the evidence: "Livestrong claims that turmeric cures cancer, however I could not find any article on google scholar. Is it true?"